# Set User Session Per user in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my default config.php, all user session will expired base on the value provided

```
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

And I have a specific user that I need to set session expiration different from the others, lets say 15 minutes

This is what I tried

SomeController

```
  function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('store_manager/Storemanager_model');
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $data = array(
    'username' => $session_data['username'],
    );

    $this->session->sess_expiration = '300';// expires in 15 minutes
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);// set session
}
```

Does not work, returns blank page

> Update

I modify this code adding some condition

```
   function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('store_manager/Storemanager_model');
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $user = $session_data['username'];

        if ($user == 'retailer_1')
        {
            //set session to non-expiring
            $this->session->sess_expiration = '32140800'; //~ one year
           // $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'false';
        }
    }
}
```

Still getting blank page

Comment: have you load session library in autoload.php or before use?

Comment: what are you getting from this line 
$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

Comment: The username value

Comment: @Shivani Patel, session is autoloaded in autoload.php

Comment: @Zeeshan The username value of the logged in user

Comment: [HERE](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-31039.html) is answer of your question. you need to create `MY_Session` class and override some methods

Comment: check if you are getting any error by enabling your development environment